# Condensing multiple while loops

Tags: python, while-loop, chess

I am undertaking the (somewhat ambitious) project of writing a chess game to be played in a Mac Terminal, using algebraic notation inputs to effect the moves.

I have written my board as a list of lists, with each nested list serving as a rank (horizontal line) on the board:

```
board = [['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
['bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP', 'bP'],
['e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e '],
['e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e '],
['e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e '],
['e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e ', 'e '],
['wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP', 'wP'],
['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']
]
```

I have then written a (rather long) procedure to check what legal moves are available for a piece, based exclusively on the input given by the user of the desired move s/he would like to make.

I am trying to make my code less repetitive, but I am having trouble generating the list of possible moves for bishops, rooks, and the queen. For example, for a bishop, I first use the given input to locate the bishop that could move to that particular square and store its position. Then, I generate a list of possible squares to which the bishop can move, using a while loop to go in the direction of each diagonal. It ends up looking like:

```
 elif piece == 'B':
      s,d = square[0] + square[1], square[0] - square[1]
      squares = [(r,f) for r in range(-8,0) for f in range(len(board)) if r-f == d or r+f==s]
      pos_bishop=[]
      for i in squares:
          pos = board[i[0]][i[1]]
          if pos == mover:
              pos_bishop.append(i[0])
              pos_bishop.append(i[1])
              break
      if len(pos_bishop) == 0:
          return False
      squares2 = []
      j,k = pos_bishop[0], pos_bishop[1]
      while j>-8 and k>0 and board[j-1][k-1] == 'e ':
          squares2.append((j-1,k-1))
          j-=1
          k-=1
      j,k = pos_bishop[0], pos_bishop[1]
      while j>-8 and k<8 and board[j-1][k+1] == 'e ':
          squares2.append((j-1,k+1))
          j-=1
          k+=1
      j,k = pos_bishop[0], pos_bishop[1]
      while j<-1 and k>0 and board[j+1][k-1] == 'e ':
          squares2.append((j+1,k-1))
          j+=1
          k-=1
      j,k = pos_bishop[0], pos_bishop[1]
      while j<-1 and k<8 and board[j+1][k+1] == 'e ':
          squares2.append((j+1,k+1))
          j+=1
          k+=1
      if square in squares2:
          return True
```

As you can see, there are four 'while' loops, and at the start of each I have to redefine the position variables. This seems unwieldy, but I am having trouble thinking of a different way to generate the moves in a more efficient manner. (I am not yet working on if the move is a capture, btw, just seeing if the square is empty.)

I would appreciate a push in the right direction rather than just an explicit solution; but any advice would be welcome. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: thinking of a different way to generate the moves in a more efficient manner.

If you generalize it, using a `function`, you can use it for other `pices` as well.
Adding the four other directions, and the knowledge of *"which moves are valid for the given pice"*, this `function` can be use for *all* pices

For example:

```
def compute_moves(pb0, pb1):
    m = []

    def get_moves(j, k, direction):
        if direction == 'sw':
            while j > -8 and k > 0 and board[j - 1][k - 1] == 'e ':
                m.append((j - 1, k - 1))
                j -= 1
                k -= 1
        elif direction == 'nw':
            while j > -8 and k < 8 and board[j - 1][k + 1] == 'e ':
                m.append((j - 1, k + 1))
                j -= 1
                k += 1
        elif direction == 'se':
            while j < -1 and k > 0 and board[j + 1][k - 1] == 'e ':
                m.append((j + 1, k - 1))
                j += 1
                k -= 1
        elif direction == 'ne':
            while j < -1 and k < 8 and board[j + 1][k + 1] == 'e ':
                m.append((j + 1, k + 1))
                j += 1
                k += 1

    for direction in ['sw', 'nw', 'se', 'ne']:
        get_moves(pb0, pb1, direction)

    return m       


if __name__ in "__main__":
    moves = compute_moves(pos_bishop[0], pos_bishop[1])
```